# Java - array stuck in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to fill an array from keyboard input, but my method gets stuck on the `b = in.nextInt();` line, in the second to last value I want to input. I'm confused.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         int a_size; 
         int duplicate; 
         System.out.println("Enter test size");
         a_size = in.nextInt();
         int [] a_array; 
         a_array = new int[a_size];
           int b;
         for (int i= 0; i <a_array.length; i++ ){
             System.out.println("Enter number"); 
             b = in.nextInt();
             a_array[i] = b;
             }
           System.out.println("Passed");
  }
```

edit: Sorry all the kind folks. I tested the code and its working fine. It was a simple code and I could not see anything wrong with it. I apologize and I agree that I am a bundle of sticks. Please forgive me.

Comment: Instead of blocking, what do you think it should do and why? Why is the blocking unexpected?

Comment: Works for me, actually

Comment: You should also say what you enter. Is it a number? Or something else?

Comment: Are you pressing `Enter` once value is been given through keyboard? This might help you  [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: tested then delete the question because it's not a **question** anymore :D

Answer (score 0):

```
in.nextInt();
```

is waiting for you to enter from the keyboard, that is why it stuck